# WPF especific style on selected item according to the style of the item

Tags: wpf

I have a custom combobox where I apply a specific style on the first item. I want that when this item is selected, the style of displayed text in the combobox is the same. Currently, all selected items appear in the same style and I do not know how to make the ContentPresenter "get" the specified style in that item. This is the code:

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200">
    <ComboBoxItem Style="{StaticResource mySpecialStyle}">Select an option...</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>ComboBox Item #3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

In fact, "mySpecialStyle" only changes color and fontstyle. But when the first item is selected, it appears like any other selected item. How can set this on the Contentpresenter?

Here is the complete code of the custom ComBoBox:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="mySpecialStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border
              x:Name="Border" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              CornerRadius="3"
              Background="#FFFAFAFA"
              BorderBrush="#FF999999"
              BorderThickness="1" />
            <Border
              x:Name="Background"
              Grid.Column="0"
              CornerRadius="3,0,0,3" 
              Margin="1"
              Background="#FFFAFAFA" 
              BorderBrush="#FF999999"
              BorderThickness="0" />
            <Path 
              x:Name="ArrowDw"
              Grid.Column="1"     
              Fill="#FF404040"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
            <Path 
              x:Name="ArrowUp"
              Grid.Column="1"     
              Fill="Transparent"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M 0 2 L 4 -2 L 8 2 Z"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="ArrowDw" Property="Fill" Value="#FF000000" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Background" Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF000000" />
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                <Setter TargetName="ArrowDw" Property="Fill" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter TargetName="ArrowUp" Property="Fill" Value="#FF404040" />
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter TargetName="ArrowUp" Property="Fill" Value="#FF000000" />
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#CCCCCC" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                <Setter TargetName="ArrowDw" Property="Fill" Value="#999999" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="27"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=SelectionBoxItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton 
                          Name="ToggleButton" 
                          Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
                          Grid.Column="2" 
                          Focusable="false"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                          ClickMode="Press">
                        </ToggleButton>

                        <ContentPresenter
                          Name="ContentSite"
                          IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"

                          ????

                          Margin="8,3,28,3"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                          Style="{x:Null}" 
                          Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          Margin="8,3,28,3"
                          Focusable="True" 
                          Background="Transparent"
                          Visibility="Hidden"
                          IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                        <Popup 
                          Name="Popup"
                          Placement="Bottom"
                          IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                          AllowsTransparency="True" 
                          Focusable="False"
                          PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid 
                              Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border 
                                  x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                  Background="#FFFFFF"
                                  BorderThickness="1"
                                  BorderBrush="#FF999999"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="27"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The placeholder "???" is where I need to set the style according to the style defined in the ComboBoxitem (in this case, "mySpecialStyle").

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ComboBox` is an ItemsControl but you re-template it to just a ContentControl (with ContentPresenter)?

Comment: The template is larger than the one presented. Actually, I only display the ContentPresenter, because it is just in it that I need set the text style. How can I bind it to the style of the corrrespondent ComboBoxItem?

Comment: it depends on the position of `ContentPresenter`. As far as I know the context of each item should be such as in an `ItemTemplate` not in a ControlTemplate like this.

Comment: I will edit the question and put all the code.

Comment: you want to add style for Item which is in selected state now ?

Comment: when you change the selected item,the item's fontstyle and should change right? or you need anyother than this?

Comment: You see that the first item has a italic font style. But when I select it, it appears in the ComboBox as the others (without italic). I want it to keep the italic style, even when it is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic to solve here of course will base on something like a `Trigger`. However we can't set `Style` via `Setter`. So I thought of this hack (but safe enough). Firstly you need to bind the `Style` of the `ContentPresenter` to its `Tag` property (of course 2 way binding by default). Then you just need to change the `Tag` to a `{StaticResource}` with `ResourceKey` being the same as the resource you defined upwards on the tree. This resource should of course have `TargetType` of `ContentPresenter`:

```
<ContentPresenter
    Name="ContentSite"
    IsHitTestVisible="False" 
    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
    Style="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

<!-- the additional Trigger should be added to the ControlTemplate.Triggers -->
<Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0">  
      <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" 
              Property="Tag" Value="{StaticResource mySpecialStyle}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: King King, you're the King! It works like a charm! Thanks a lot!